# Php DomDocument not finding element by Id

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I have written the following php:

```
$html = "<div id='title'>someTitle</div>";

$docToAdd = new DomDocument();
$docToAdd->validateOnParse = true;
$docToAdd->loadHTML($html);


if($docToAdd->getElementById('title') == null){
    echo "null";
}
else{
    echo $docToAdd->getElementById('title')->tagName;
}
```

Why does it echo `null` when I clearly have just added am element with id `'title'`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the HTML does not contain a [doctype declaration](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html), `getElementById` will always return `null`.